Eyes lose parent when exporting to fbx?
When i export animation to fbx and opening it in blender again, eyes seem to loose parent and they don't follow head anymore. Rig was made with rigify. Please help, any tips welcome. I attached file.


I don't know why it is designed this way, but Rigify doesn't provide deform bones for eyes and teeth, and requires you to have all of them as individual objects and individually parent them to their controller bone through bone parenting or Child Of Constraints.
You went with bone parenting. And it works... If you do not leave Blender. If you do what half the Rigify users do: exporting, then you need to change the rig to make it export ready.
Make the eyes weight-based deformed
On Rig Creation
Good to know, when you create a new metarig, you are given the option to update the face rig which does support bone deform out of the box:

After creation
Before anything, set your armature to Rest Pose. Select your eyes and teeth objects in object mode, and press Ctrl P > Clear Parent And Keep Transformation.
Simplest way (and better since you have custom eye bones anyway): unhide your metarig, go in pose mode, select the eyes placement bones, and enable their rigify deform option, and regenerate the rig:

Otherwise, with the old face rig: in edit mode on your armature, select your eyes and teeth controller bones, hold down ⎇ Alt and enable their Deform option:

Then in object mode, select your eyes and teeth object, and finally your armature, parent with empty groups.
Then for each eye and teeth object, go in edit mode, select all the mesh, select its bone's vertex group and hit assign:

Exporting
When exporting, select the deformed mesh objects and the armature before running the export. And in the export options, enable "Only Selected", and for the armature options, "Only Deform Bones" and not "Add Leaf Bones":

Result:


Thank you for reply. I will test this method with next model. What also helped me was applying modifiers to eye objects. Will be also testing fbx exporter addon  as I heard it can help with rigify exports
